# Run trace.py with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, trace, pytest-cov

I'm trying to get coverage using `trace.py` when running `pytest`. I know that `pytest` has its own coverage plugin `pytest-cov` but restrictions (number of times each line is executed is unavailable) do not allow me to use that right now. The same for `coverage.py`

I'm trying this command:
`python3.4 -m trace -c -m -C . pytest test_script.py`

`test_script.py`:

```
class TestScript():
    def test_print(self):
        print ('Hello')
```

The output is:

```
nikhilh$ python3.4 -m trace -c -m -C . pytest test_script.py
pytest: Cannot run file 'pytest' because: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pytest'
```

`trace.py` obviously expects a file in its arguments and not another module. How can I modify this command to get `trace.py` working with `pytest`?

Edit:
I was able to find a way to get this done

`nikhilh$ python3.4 -m trace -c -m -C . <pytest_script_absolute_path> test_script.py`

Comment: I realize its been a bit since you posted this but could you make your solution an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run python's trace with pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381237/how-do-i-run-pythons-trace-with-pytest)

Comment: @hoefling yep, that answer is what I came up with too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across David's comment, so here's the answer that I used at that time:

`python3.4 -m trace -c -m -C . <pytest_script_absolute_path> test_script.py`

Comment: Where can I find the `pytest_script_absolute_path`? I assume this means the script that is called when running `pytest` from terminal...

Comment: Just followed the [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381237/how-do-i-run-pythons-trace-with-pytest) and was reminded of `which pytest` (or `where pytest` on Windows)