# How do I run python's trace with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, trace, bin

I am trying to run a trace on a program that is executed with pytest.
I am trying the command

```
python3 -m trace -t  pytest test_one.py
```

but it is giving me

```
Cannot run file 'pytest' because: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pytest'
```

as I am assuming trace.py is expecting a file. I saw this 
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747733/run-trace-py-with-pytest) but I'm a bit struggling to understand what   is supposed to mean - is it supposed to be the executable file for pytest itself (I actually don't see where that is on my computer, I found a folder to a main.py and init.py but I can't seem to see some executable), or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's actually the `pytest` executable itself. Under *nix, you should be able to localize it using `which pytest`, under Windows it's located under `Scripts` (in the virtual enviroment, or the Python installation path, depending on what you use).

Comment: I would see this as a duplicate of the referenced question, but that one has no accepted answer (only a comment with the answer).

Comment: `which pytest` on Unix is `where pytest` on Windows. @MrBeanBremen why not adding an answer yourself? The question is more than a year old, it's unlikely that the OP will give an answer any time soon.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in a comment to the referenced question, you have to substitute `pytest` by the actual path to the pytest executable:

```
python -m trace -c -m -C . <pytest_executable_absolute_path> test_script.py
```

Under *nix, you should be able to localize the `pytest` executable using `which pytest`, under Windows using `where pytest` (thanks to @hoefling for reminding me of that).