# Hunt for root cause of flaky test in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, trace

There is a flaky test, and we have no clue what the root cause could be.

```
with pytest.raises(foo.geocoder.GeocodingFailed):
    foo.geocoder.geocode('not a valid place')
```

Sometimes the exception does not happen.

I looked at the docs [how to handle failures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/failures.html), but this did not help.

How to trace `geocode()` so that if the exception does not happen, I see a trace?

I looked at the `trace` module of the standard library. But there seems to be no easy way to get the trace as string.

With "a trace" I mean: A trace of all lines which got executed during `gecode()`. I would like to see method calls and returns statements with indentation. I want to ignore lines from the Python standard library.

AFAIK a debugger like pdb does not help here, since the test only fails when it gets run in CI, and only once or twice per month.

Comment: Not sure about this but putting this in a try except wont help? (with the the except taking in any exceptions)

Comment: @PiyushSingh i want to see a trace if there was no exception. Putting this in a try-except wont help.

Comment: Have you tried dropping into pdb using `--pdb` command? Using `--trace` drops you to the pdb before test execution. `--pdb` drops you to the frame where test failure happens. I think that will be more useful for you in this case.

Comment: @SilentGuy AFAIK a debugger like pdb does not help here, since the test only fails when it gets run in CI, and only once or twice very month.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share more info about geocode? I assume you can modify geocode in any way you see fit?

Comment: Try running tests with higher log verbosity to give you some clue. Use `-vvvv --log-cli-level=debug ` to get debug logging from python modules. You can also add your own logging at places where you think problem might lie. Maybe that will help.

Comment: @SilentGuy I can add many "v" characters to the command line. This won't give me a trace which shows every executed line (like `set -x` for bash).

Comment: Have you tried this `python -m trace -c -m -C . <pytest_script_absolute_path> test_script.py` ? From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60382771/2312300

Comment: @SilentGuy the above test gets called in the CI of a big project. I don't want to change the way the test suite gets executed for this single test. I think it should be possible to get a trace (like bash `set -x`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `trace` module gives programmatic access via `trace.Trace` class.
On test failures the `Trace` class' console output is visible.
And it has coverage report to write on chosen path.

I exclude `sys.base_exec_prefix`, `sys.base_prefix` to not trace Python library modules.

```
import pytest


def f(x):
    import random

    choice = random.choice((True, False))

    if choice:
        raise ValueError
    else:
        return x * 2


def trace(f, *args, **kwargs):
    import trace
    import sys

    tracer = trace.Trace(
        ignoredirs=(sys.base_exec_prefix, sys.base_prefix), timing=True,
    )
    ret = tracer.runfunc(f, *args, **kwargs)
    r = tracer.results()
    r.write_results(coverdir="/tmp/xx-trace")
    return ret


def test_f():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        trace(f, 3)
```

[image: pytest run]

Coverage report;
Lines marked with >>>>>> were not executed i.e. not traced and the numbers with colon are execution counts.

```
>>>>>> import pytest
       
       
>>>>>> def f(x):
    1:     import random
       
    1:     choice = random.choice((True, False))
       
    1:     if choice:
>>>>>>         raise ValueError
           else:
    1:         return x * 2
       
       
>>>>>> def trace(f, *args, **kwargs):
>>>>>>     import trace
>>>>>>     import sys
       
>>>>>>     tracer = trace.Trace(
>>>>>>         ignoredirs=(sys.base_exec_prefix, sys.base_prefix), timing=True,
           )
>>>>>>     tracer.runfunc(f, *args, **kwargs)
>>>>>>     r = tracer.results()
>>>>>>     r.write_results(coverdir="/tmp/xx-trace")
       
       
>>>>>> def test_f():
>>>>>>     with pytest.raises(ValueError):
>>>>>>         trace(f, 3)
```

Comment: This would be really cool if it was an autouse fixture.

Answer (score 3):

The `trace` library does not help, as it does not enable writing to a `string` or a `StringIO` object, it only writes to *real* files.

What you can do is to use `sys.settrace()` and define a simple function, which is called for every execution. You will find the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace.
The basic magic is to get the details out of the `frame`object, which is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html.

A sample to give you an idea looks like this:

```
import sys


def tracer(frame, event, arg):
    print(frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno, event, arg)


def bad_function(param: int):
    if param == 20:
        raise RuntimeError(f'that failed for {param}')


sys.settrace(tracer)

bad_function(1)
bad_function(20)
bad_function(2)
```

It should be easy to store that information into a string for further investigation, or to handle the exception, if it is raised.

Comment: thank you for your answer. BTW, in your profile you link to https://pythonmeister.com/. If I try to access this site, I get "Data privacy exeption" with Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`pytest-repeat`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/) with `--pdb`.

Something like `pytest test_geocode.py --count 10 --pdb`. This could work if your CI works in a docker container and you can connect to the container.

Alternatively, Jenkins allows you to pause on failure and then investigate that way, but since it's flaky and only happens once or twice a month, then literally adding the `--pdb` flag to be part of the CI so that you can connect whenever it happens. You would need a way to notify you that it has entered this flow though otherwise the build may time out. But if you keep a close eye on your builds it may not be an issue.

Additionally, if you're not already using [`pytest-html`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/) it may be worth integrating to get a nice report of what went on (via log lines) and what failed or just using

`pytest test_geocode.py --log-file=/path/to/log/file --log-file-level=DEBUG`.

Attaching either the pytest html report and or the log file as artefacts to failed builds will allow for better debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But somehow you explain a different solution. I want to see the lines (like in the  bash `set -x`) if the assertion fails.

Comment: @guettli ty btw in future i'd recommend a real example in your question, with the actual output of `set -x` I saw your comments but i didnt understand; although im quiet proficient in bash!